# "Any vs. "any other" and "every" vs. "every other"

Tags: determiners, comparisons

Can you please clarify what difference in meanings exists between the sentences in the following two pairs:

> 1. - Tom is taller than any boy present in the class.
>    - Tom is taller than any other boy present in the class.
> 2. - Tom is taller than every boy present in the class.
>    - Tom is taller than every other boy present in the class.

Comment: First, there's no meaning difference between the (a) and (b) versions. Tom can't be taller than himself, so the truth set is identical. Second, _any_ is a Negative Polarity Item, and that means it can only occur in a negative context, and the _than_ clause of a comparative construction is such a context. And **that** means that it doesn't really mean _every_, outside such a context. For instance, _She wonders whether Tom likes everybody in the class_ does **not** mean the same thing as _She wonders whether Tom likes anybody in the class_

Comment: For "negative polarity", [search here](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a15299%20negative%20polarity).

Comment: It seems that this question contains two. I have asked first part here, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184322

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that, assuming that Tom is in the class at the time, the second in each example pair is *grammatically* and logically correct, while the first is not. Because Tom cannot be taller than himself, saying he's taller than any boy there is nonsensical. More obviously, "New York is bigger than any city in America". Nonsense, unless the New York referred to is not in America. This, BTW, is one of the most common mistakes made in speech and in writing. "He's smarter than anyone!", etc.

Comment: Do you mean that "He's smarter than anyone!" is wrong? What's the right way of saying it?

Comment: A mathematician would say that a set is a subset of itself. So it depends. Nice point, though.