# What is the difference between “any” or ”every”?

Tags: differences, determiners, writing-advice, any-every

Consider:

> The system is deterministic if any two runs produce the same result.

Can I say *every* instead of *any* in every such sentence?

Comment: Which else kinds of equivalence do we have?

Comment: Those two sentences are grammatically equivalent, but semantically and logically ***very*** different. _Any two runs_ means that out of however many runs were done in total, any randomly chosen pair of runs (say, run number 112 and run number 2,058) should produce the same result. _Every two runs_ means either every second run (numbers 1, 3, 5, 7, etc.), or every single pair of runs. So yes, you can say both—but they mean quite different things.

Comment: This question is actually a logic / statistics / systems / mathematics question and not an english question.

Comment: @AhmedMasud If I said `any lion is a cat` you would reject the question as "zoological rather than english". You should alwayws find a reason to reject a question and with some disregard it is not difficult.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I guess that `Arnold is a father` is grammatically equivalent to `Bookshelf was empty` but that raises a question what is the purpose to ask for grammatical equivalence. Anyway, what is `every single pair` and how is it (logically/semantically) different from `any random pair`? I read a book on semantics in logic (logic = grammatics + semantics and these 3 things are different, so that logic is not semantics) and it says that you can prove things (semantically) different by counterexample. Can you demonstrate one which distinguishes `any random pair` from `every single pair`?

Comment: I mean that logic equivalence means that one implies the other. That is not the case if things are different. Can you show that I have property which holds for `any random pair` but does not for `every single pair` or vice versa? Actually, book says that every language has a grammar and semantics. I am asking about semantics of english language.

Comment: @Val No, those two are not grammatically equivalent, because one of them is grammatical and the other is not. The difference between _any_ and _every_ here is a practical one: with _any_, you pick two random runs and compare them, and that's all you need. With _every_, you have to compare every single possible combination of runs to know whether the system is deterministic or not. Or alternatively, you'd have to evaluate 50% of all runs, if you take it to mean ‘every second run’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think that I understand the semantics of English. That is the answer. But, logically/semantically, how do you have `any random` true if property does not hold for `every single`? How do you ensure that without checking every single first and vice versa? One should imply the other. This means that they are logically equivalent.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet 'If any two shapes are identical' could be argued to have the meaning 'if any randomly selected pair of shapes are found to be identical, no matter how many pairs are selected'. Not the sense I'd opt for, but not inconceivable. This is known as **scope ambiguity** which quantifiers are sadly susceptible to. The usual example given, as here at [Saarland](http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/projects/milca/courses/comsem/html/node92.html) , is `Every man loves a woman.' I prefer 'A man is knocked down in Britain every twenty minutes. And he's getting really fed up about it.' (TC?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Any** is polysemous.

[AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/any):

> any [quantifier]
>
> 1. One, some, every, or all without specification

choosing examples:

> Are there any messages for me?

[meaning one or some]

> Any child would love that.

[meaning every]

But

> The system is deterministic if any two runs produce the same result.

is itself an example of a **scope ambiguity**:

Do we mean

The system is deterministic if there have been / are any two runs producing the same result.

or

The system is deterministic if all the possible selected pairs of runs produce the same result. (when it would be clearer just to say The system is deterministic if all runs produce the same result).

Perhaps a clearer illustration of this ambiguity is:

If any child can afford to come [we'll ask their parents to contribute to the new library].

If any child can afford to come [we'll need two coaches].

Comment: With the child sentences, your second option doesn't seem right to me. It'd be "If every child can afford to come we'll need two coaches". I think perhaps "If any child can afford to come then the trip will go ahead" might work better.

Comment: The sentence works; in speech, 'any' would be stressed. From the internet: _Search engine results pages (SERPS) would be a pretty horrible collection if any lazy Tom, Dick or Harry could come along and get a place_ An alternative is to use 'just any' (or sometimes 'any old') which disambiguates: _Imagine if just any two animals could mate with each other_ . [internet]

Comment: I like "just any" and "any old" as ways of clarifying things. In the children example "any one" can disambiguate in another direction (towards my version above). You can do something similar in the original with "...if any one pair of runs produce the same results".

Answer (score 3):

Any thing means considering **one** of the things.

Every thing is considering **all** the things individually.

Mostly they can be used interchangeably **but** "any" usually means negatively. For example:

-- You can use every thing that you have.

-- You cannot use any thing!

Answer (score 1):

*Any* stands for *any random pick*, while *every* stands for *every single*.

Grammatically, these are different phrases, but, if we think carefully, they mean the same thing. So, you can use both equivalently. If they were not, there would exist a counterexample. There must be one since there are people in the question’s comments who oppose my claim. But they fail to provide the counterexample needed to support that position.

Comment: You don't seem to be considering that 'any two runs' producing the same result can also mean runs 22 and 47 say, where all the rest give different results, showing that the equivalence of results 22 and 47 was a fluke. 'Every two runs' here would be taken to have the alternative sense that Janus cites. This is the way English works – not as logically as some might like. 'The system is deterministic if all runs produce the same result.' sounds more sensible to me, unless I'm misinterpreting.

Comment: That's **one** sense of _any_, what Vendler 1967 calls "free-choice _any_"; there is also Negative Polarity _any_, (as in _I didn't see any apples_) which is much more frequent.